# Determining whether MATLAB fitglm() model fit converged

Tags: matlab, statistics, iteration, diagnostics, convergence

There are many MATLAB functions that do some kind of statistical model fitting, such as `fitglm()`. These model fits can fail to converge for various reasons; this question is NOT about what can cause such failures or about how to prevent them.

My question is: is there a way, other than by looking at the console output, to determine if a given call to `fitglm()` converged? The obvious way to do this would seem to be through some property of the output arguments, but the list of properties of the [Linear Model class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html%20model%20class) doesn't seem to contain this basic information.

A minimal example (inspired by [this question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153259-how-to-fix-iteration-limit-reached-warning)):

```
x = [7 0;0 0;8 0;9 0;7 1;8 0;7 0;4 0;7 0;2 0];
y = [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]';
m = fitglm(x,y,'distr','binomial');

Warning: Iteration limit reached.
```

What, if anything, about the output `m` tells us that the iteration limit was reached?

Answer (score 2):

I have yet to find any such information in the [`GeneralizedLinearModel` class object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmodel-class.html) returned from [`fitglm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitglm.html). However, one option which *technically* avoids looking at the console output is to capture information about the last warning using either [`lastwarn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lastwarn.html) or [`warning`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html):

```
>> [lastMsg, lastID] = lastwarn

lastMsg =

Iteration limit reached.

lastID =

stats:glmfit:IterationLimit


>> w = warning('query', 'last')

w = 

  struct with fields:

    identifier: 'stats:glmfit:IterationLimit'
         state: 'on'
```

Note that this will still work even if [warnings have been suppressed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html) (i.e. warnings are still generated and stored, but not displayed).

One way you could use this is to first set the last warning to a dummy message (using `lastwarn`), then fit your model, then get the last warning again and compare it to your dummy message. If it's different, a new warning was thrown when fitting the model:

```
lastwarn('Nothing to see here', 'this:is:not:a:warning');
m = fitglm(x, y, 'distr', 'binomial');
[lastMsg, lastID] = lastwarn;
warningWasThrown = ~strcmp(lastID, 'this:is:not:a:warning');
```

In addition, you could have a [switch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement that checks the value of the warning identifier `lastID` and takes different actions accordingly, like attempting the model fit with an alternate set of parameters.

Comment: @MattMizumi: Yeah, I was a little surprised they didn't return this kind of information, either as another output or a property of the model object. Maybe they intended for the warning messages alone to be used for this.